# JFace TableViewer invalid text position in first column if some cells contain an icon

Tags: java, swt, jface, tableviewer

I noticed that JFace TableViewer has some troubles with displaying text in the first column (only) if other cells in other columns contain icons. Additional space before text appears. I don't think this issue has not been found yet, so possibly some additional configuration is required. Here is a sample:

[image: What is this blank space for?]

And simple code to test:

```java
public class IconTest {
private static class MyContentProvider implements IStructuredContentProvider {
    public Object[] getElements(Object inputElement) {
        return new String[] { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight",
                "nine", "ten" };
    }

    public void dispose() {

    }

    public void inputChanged(Viewer viewer, Object oldInput, Object newInput) {

    }
}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    TableViewer v = new TableViewer(shell, SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
    v.getTable().setLinesVisible(true);
    v.getTable().setHeaderVisible(true);
    v.setContentProvider(new MyContentProvider());

    CellLabelProvider labelProvider = new CellLabelProvider() {

        public void update(ViewerCell cell) {
            cell.setText(cell.getElement().toString());
        }
    };

    CellLabelProvider labelProvider2 = new CellLabelProvider() {
        public void update(ViewerCell cell) {
            cell.setText(cell.getElement().toString());
            cell.setImage(Display.getDefault().getSystemImage(SWT.ICON_QUESTION));
        }
    };

    TableViewerColumn column = new TableViewerColumn(v, SWT.NONE);
    column.setLabelProvider(labelProvider);
    column.getColumn().setText("Column 1");
    column.getColumn().setWidth(100);

    TableViewerColumn column2 = new TableViewerColumn(v, SWT.NONE);
    column2.setLabelProvider(labelProvider2);
    column2.getColumn().setText("Column 2");
    column2.getColumn().setWidth(100);

    v.setInput("");

    shell.setSize(400, 400);
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }

    display.dispose();
}
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a long standing known issue - see Eclipse bug report [43910](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=43910) (from 2004!)

The bug report is saying that the underlying Windows table code behaves like this and there is nothing SWT/JFace can do about it.

You may be able to work around this by using `OwnerDrawLabelProvider` which provides full control of how the cell is drawn. `StyledCellLabelProvider` is derived for `OwnerDrawLabelProvider` and is easier to use.